# confliction type for a user defined function in c

Tags: c, dev-c++

I am working in c after a long time.Here i have to achieve three functionality which includes

1. get a number and show half

2.Get the square of the number

3.Get two number and show their summation and sabtraction.

I am using devC++ and when i compile the code i get the error i mentioned in the title which `conflict type if squareInput`.What is wrong here:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(){

    float x;
    printf("enter a number\n");
    scanf("%f",&x);

    //TASK 1 : display half of the number 
    pirntf("half of x is = %.3f",x);

    //TASK 2 : square of number 

    squareInput(x); //call square function from here

    // TASK 3 : get two numbers and display both summation and sabtraction

    float num1,num2;   // declare two floating number( floating numbers can hold decimal point numbers
    printf("enter num1 \n");
    scanf("num1 is =%f",&num1);
    printf("enter num2 \n");
    scanf("num2 is =%f",num2);
    calculate(num1,num2);// call calculate function

    getch();
}

float squareInput(float input){

    float square=input*input;
    printf("\n square of the number is %.3f \n",square);
    return 0;
}

float calculate(float num1,float num2){

    //summation
    float summation= num1+num2; // declare antoher variable called summation to hold the sum 
    //sabtraction
    float sabtraction=num1-num2;

    printf("summation is %.2f \n",summation);
    printf("sabtraction is %.2f \n",sabtraction);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since the code is being compiled using C++, please remove the `c` tag.

Comment: the header file `conio.h` is not portable.  Suggest replacing the calls to `getch()` with `getchar()` and remove the `#include <conio.h>` statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Things will go wrong without prototypes. Add

```
float squareInput(float input);
float calculate(float num1,float num2);
```

in front of `int main()`.

If you don't declare a function before it's called, the compiler assumes it as a int-returning function. However, `squareInput()` return float, so the compiler(or linker, maybe) complains to you.

Also note that definitions are declarations(but not vice versa, obviously), so moving the definitions of `squareInput()` and `calculate()` in front of where they are called works too.

Comment: why?,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: @AL-zami, because that's how the symbol lookup is defined in `c`.

Comment: previous time i wrote them in codeblock didn't require it

Comment: @AL-zami, the compiler did you a disservice than

Comment: @AL-zami: Because if you're using C99 or C11, you are not allowed to use a function without a declaration in scope, and if you're stuck behind the times with C89/C90, then the undeclared functions will be assumed to return `int` (and your `float` value will be converted to `double` when the function is called), but that is not the correct return type.

Comment: @AL-zami Also, note that prototypes aren't required if you define the function before the definition of `main`.

Answer (score 5):

At the time you call `squareInput` and `calculate`, they haven't been defined yet.  So C assumes an implicit declaration of `int squareInput()` and `int calculate()`.  These implicit declarations conflict with the definitions of these functions.

You can fix this by either adding declarations for each of these functions before `main`:

```
float squareInput(float input);
float calculate(float num1,float num2);
```

Or by simply moving the functions in their entirety before `main`.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to add prototypes when you use a function. That way you do not need to worry too much about the order in which you call them.

Also try to separate your problems into smaller bits if you can. A comment like TAKS1 shows you that you actually want a function with that name.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//prototypes
void AskUserForOneNumer(float * number, const char * question );
void TASK_1(float x);
void TASK_2(float x);
void TASK_3(float a, float b);

int main()
{
    float x, a, b;
    AskUserForOneNumer(&x, "enter x");
    AskUserForOneNumer(&a, "enter a");
    AskUserForOneNumer(&b, "enter b");
    TASK_1(x);
    TASK_2(x);
    TASK_3(a, b);
}

void TASK_1(float x)
{
    printf("x = %g\n", x);
    printf("0.5 * x = %g\n", 0.5 * x);
}

void TASK_2(float x)
{
    printf("x = %g\n", x);
    printf("x * x = %g\n", x * x);
}

void TASK_3(float a, float b)
{
    printf("a = %g\n", a);
    printf("b = %g\n", b);
    printf("a + b = %g\n", a + b);
    printf("a - b = %g\n", a - b);
}

void AskUserForOneNumer(float * number, const char * question)
{
    float x;
    printf("%s\n", question);
    scanf("%f", &x);
    printf("your input was %g\n", x);
    *number = x;
}
```