# c language printf float error

Tags: c

I define a function finding the mean value of an array of int, the function is as follows:

```
float MeanInt(int x[],int num){
    float mean, sum = 0.0f,res=0.0f;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<num;i++){
        sum += (float)(x[i]);
        printf("x[%d] is %d\n", i,x[i]);
        printf("sum is %f\n", sum);
    }
    res = sum/((float)(num));
    printf("mean should be %f\n", res);
    return res;
}
```

the `printf()` within this function all works correctly.
The problem is that when I use it in my project, like follows:

```
printf("mean number is %f\n", MeanInt(ls_tr_acl,num_round));
```

I meet with an error saying that: 
format `%f` expects argument of type `double`, but argument 2 has type `int`
I'm fully confused because the `printf()` within the function `MeanInt()` print out exactly the correct result. I also test `MeanInt()` on some toy examples and it always works correctly. The problem only happens when I run it in my project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [confliction type for a user defined function in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35435953/confliction-type-for-a-user-defined-function-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not declaring the function `MeanInt` before its first invocation so compiler assumes the type of `MeanInt` is a function returning `int` taking any number of arguments.

**Fix**
Include appropriate header file (containing the declaration), or move the definition above usage or declare it before usage as:

```
float MeanInt(int x[],int num);
```

You can declare it at global scope at the top of the file or in narrower scope also.

Comment: You can have gcc  or MSVC warn you about this with the `-Wall` compiler option.